# Python zipping all other contents inside the same file

Tags: python, shell, zip

I'm trying to write a python script that will create a ZIP inside a "backups" directory that includes all the contents of the directory.

My file structure:

```
C:/
    Users/
        myuser/
            backups/
                blah.gif
                config.xml
                etc.
```

So I want the script to create a `C:/Users/myuser/backups/mybackup.zip` that contains all the contents of the `backups/` directory (`blah.gif`, `config.xml`, etc.).

Here is the code I'm using:

```
backupDir = "C:/Users/myuser/backups/"
backupFile = "mybackup.zip"
file = zipfile.ZipFile(backupDir + backupFile, "w")
for name in glob.glob(backupDir):
    print "Found " + name
    file.write(name, os.path.basename(name), zipfile.ZIP_DEFLATED)
file.close()
```

When I run this it produces a `C:/Users/myuser/backups/mybackup.zip` file but when I unzip it, it's empty. Where am I going astray? Thanks in advance!

Comment: http://www.xinotes.org/notes/note/1034/  ... Also I think the zipfile is created in the backupDir as soon as you say `file = ...` and then its in the glob so its trying to add itself to itself... which I dont think will work... and probably breaks the whole process...instead save it to C:\Windows\Temp\backup.zip ...may help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

glob expect a pattern match. I prefer to use os.listdir() because it is easier to use.

```
backupDir = "C:/Users/myuser/backups/"
backupFile = "mybackup.zip"
file = zipfile.ZipFile(backupDir + backupFile, "w")
for name in os.listdir(backupDir):
    if name == backupFile:
        continue
    fullname = backupDir + name
    print "Found " + name
    file.write(fullname, os.path.basename(name), zipfile.ZIP_DEFLATED)
file.close()
```

Comment: You should use `os.path.join(backupDir, backupFile)` instead of `backupDir + backupFile`. The result in this case is the same, but in case you ever forgot the trailing `/` from the first parameter, `os.path.join` would save you. Furthermore, in order to avoid the `if` statement, you could do `filesToZip = list(os.listdir(backupDir))` before calling `ZipFile`.

Comment: simple is better than complex :)

Comment: explicit is better than implicit :)